# Change number of displayed point events in Woocommerce "Points & Rewards" plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, points

I'm using the WooCommerce "Points & Rewards" plugin to add points to customers.
The customer can view the history of his points in his account.
At the moment there are only 5 point events displayed in the account page of the user.

I found the function in the plugin:

```
function woocommerce_points_rewards_my_points() {
    global $wc_points_rewards;

    $points_balance = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::get_users_points( get_current_user_id() );
    $points_label   = $wc_points_rewards->get_points_label( $points_balance );

    $count = apply_filters( 'wc_points_rewards_my_account_points_events', 5, get_current_user_id() );

    // get a set of points events, ordered newest to oldest
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => array(
            'field' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        ),
        'per_page' => $count,
        'paged'    => 0,
        'user'     => get_current_user_id(),
    );

    $events = WC_Points_Rewards_Points_Log::get_points_log_entries( $args );

    // load the template
    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/my-points.php',
        array(
            'points_balance' => $points_balance,
            'points_label'   => $points_label,
            'events'         => $events,
        ),
        '',
        $wc_points_rewards->get_plugin_path() . '/templates/'
    );
}
```

Is there any way to override the number of events with an own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you can use `wc_points_rewards_my_account_points_events` filter hook to change the number of displayed points events, this way:

```
add_filter( 'wc_points_rewards_my_account_points_events', 'filter_wcpr_my_account_points_events', 10, 2 );
function filter_wcpr_my_account_points_events( $events, $user_id ) {
    return 20; // Change to 20 instead of 5
}
```

Or even shorter in one line:

```
add_filter( 'wc_points_rewards_my_account_points_events', function( $events, $user_id ){ return 20; }, 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.